# How to create an embed for statistical information provided by my Discord bot (Covid Statistics)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I've created a Discord bot that will give me Covid statistics on any country on command, however it's only displayed to me in raw text, I've seen images of embeds like this:

[image]

I'm interested to have my data displayed like this in my bots reply, this is the code I am using for it:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const countries = require("./countries.json");
const url = 'https://api.covid19api.com/total/country/';
const WAKE_COMMAND = 'cases';

client.on('message', async (msg) => {
  const content = msg.content.split(/[ ,]+/);
  if(content[0] === WAKE_COMMAND){
    if(content.length > 2){
      msg.reply("Too many arguments...")
    }
    else if(content.length === 1){
      msg.reply("Not enough arguments")
    }
    else if(!countries[content[1]]){
      msg.reply("Wrong country format")
    }
    else{
      const slug = content[1]
      const payload = await axios.get(`${url}${slug}`)
      const covidData = payload.data.pop();
      msg.reply(`Confirmed: ${covidData.Confirmed}, Deaths: ${covidData.Deaths}, Recovered: ${covidData.Recovered}, Active: ${covidData.Active} `)
    }
  }
});
```

Any help on how I should rearrange my code to look more like the embed above would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the [MessageEmbed](https://discord.js.org/?source=post_page---------------------------#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed) class.

Here an example of it being used:

```js
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("#0099ff")
    .setTitle("A title")
    .setDescription("A description")
    .setTimestamp()
message.channel.send(embed);

// You can also use the code below, in your case
msg.reply(embed);
```

You can find more examples of this [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html)

If you want to create something like ProDyno has, you'll want to use the `.addLine` method on the MessageEmbed class, this will allow you to toggle things like `inline` to be `true` so you can put stats next to each other. For example:

```js
.addFields(
    { name: 'Inline title', value: 'Inline text', inline: true },
    { name: 'Inline title', value: 'Inline text', inline: true },
)
```